# unable to translate the whole app using easy localization flutter

Tags: flutter, translation, flutter-localizations

I have an app where I am converting English to Arabic. I am using easy localization package. The problem I am facing is, I am only able to convert one page (the page in which I choose the English is turning to Arabic) but when I go to another page, no translation is being done. The current code is this:

```
main.dart

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(EasyLocalization(
    supportedLocales: [
      Locale("en"),
      Locale("ar"),
    ],
    path: 'assets/languages',
    saveLocale: true,
    fallbackLocale: Locale('en'),
    child:  MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

   MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
      
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
      supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales ,
      locale: context.locale,
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code in which I am converting the language from English to Arabic (I am using a drop down to change):

```
    String? dropdownvalue = 'English';
    Locale? lang = Locale("en");

    // List of items in our dropdown menu

    final language = Material(
      elevation: 0.9,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: Container(
        width: width*0.95,
        height: height*0.13,

        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150),),

        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Container(


            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: height*0.13,


                  width: width*0.16,

                  child:
                  Image.asset('assets/images/fa_language.png'),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFFF9F2E7),

                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0,bottom: 8.0,left: 15.0,right: 15.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(height: 10,),
                          Text("Language".tr().toString(),style: GoogleFonts.barlow(textStyle:  TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Barlow',fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,color:Color(0xFF222222) ),),
                          ),SizedBox(height: height*0.01,),
                          Container(
                            width: width*0.69,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 1.4, color: Color(0xFFEEEEEE)),

                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                            ),

                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 32,
                                  child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                    child: DropdownButton(
                                      iconSize: 0.0,
                                      // Initial Value
                                      value: lang,
                                      // Down Arrow Icon

                                      // Array list of items
                                        items: [
                                    DropdownMenuItem( value: Locale( 'en' ),
                                    child: Text( '   English',    style: GoogleFonts.barlow(textStyle:  TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Barlow',fontSize: 14,fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,color:Color(0xFF222222) ),),),),
                              DropdownMenuItem( value: Locale( 'ar' ),

                                child: Text( '  العربية'),),

                                  ],

                                      onChanged: (Locale? newValue) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          // lang = newValue! as Locale?;
                                          dropdownvalue="ej";
                                          context.locale = newValue!;

                                        });
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(width: width*0.47,),
                                ImageIcon(AssetImage("assets/images/downArrow.png")),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),



                        ],
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

To change the language in this page I just add this to change the language:

```
Text("hello".tr().toString());
```

and it works. But if I do the same thing in another page it does not. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not setting the app locale to your selected locale language.

Use the following code in your onChanged function in your dropDown:

```
context.setLocale(Locale('en', 'US'));
```

Comment: It works but also does not because only after I reload the application does the changes in other pages are made

Comment: The above code should work in all pages when navigating. But if you reload your app, your locale will be lost and your app falls back to the default locale you've set in main.dart.
So, for the app to hold the locale even after the user closes and starts the app from start, you need to save the local to shared_prefs. That is a completely different question to what you've asked here. So, if the above answered your question you should mark it as answer.